# Nginx SSL configuration for multiple domains on the same IP

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, http, hosting

I'm serving multiple domains from the same IP. I enabled SSL for one of them (ssobczak.net) and now I'm getting redirected instead of reaching it.

I'm getting redirected to another one: beta.coralnotes.com (which is alphabetically first one of the domains hosted on that machine).

```
> curl -i https://ssobczak.net:443/
HTTP/2 301 
location: http://beta.coralnotes.com/
(...)
```

Configs:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-available/ssobczak.net
server {
    server_name ssobczak.net;
    listen *:443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www/ssobczak.net;
    index index.php index.html;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/ssobczak.net.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/ssobczak.net.error.log debug;

    (... a few location {...} blocks here ...)

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ssobczak.net/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ssobczak.net/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

# /etc/nginx/sites-available/beta.coralnotes.com    
server {
    server_name beta.coralnotes.com;
    listen *:80;       

    root /usr/share/nginx/www/beta.coralnotes;
    index index.php;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/beta.coralnotes.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/beta.coralnotes.com.error.log debug;

    (... gzip config ...)
    (... a few location {...} blocks ...)

    # BEGIN W3TC Page Cache cache
    (...)
    # END W3TC Page Cache core

}
```

Log entries I see when executing `curl -i https://ssobczak.net:443/`:

```
==> /var/log/nginx/error.log <==
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: accept on 0.0.0.0:80, ready: 0
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: posix_memalign: 000000000101FB70:512 @16
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 accept: 141.101.104.185:15076 fd:19
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 event timer add: 19: 60000:1544883627407
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 reusable connection: 1
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 epoll add event: fd:19 op:1 ev:80002001
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http wait request handler
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 malloc: 0000000001212470:1024
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 recv: eof:0, avail:1
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 recv: fd:19 290 of 1024
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 reusable connection: 0
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 posix_memalign: 00000000010314A0:4096 @16
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http process request line
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http request line: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http uri: "/"
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http args: ""
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http exten: ""
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 posix_memalign: 000000000120F070:4096 @16
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http process request header line
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http header: "Host: ssobczak.net"
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http header: "Connection: Keep-Alive"
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip"
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http header: "CF-IPCountry: PL"
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http header: "X-Forwarded-For: 89.75.69.70"
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http header: "CF-RAY: 48998b975dbf9bd5-AMS"
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http header: "X-Forwarded-Proto: https"
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http header: "CF-Visitor: {"scheme":"https"}"
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http header: "user-agent: curl/7.54.0"
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http header: "accept: */*"
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http header: "CF-Connecting-IP: 89.75.69.70"
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http header done
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 event timer del: 19: 1544883627407
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 generic phase: 0
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 rewrite phase: 1
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http set discard body
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http script var: "http"
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http script copy: "://beta.coralnotes.com"
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http script var: "/"
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http finalize request: 301, "/?" a:1, c:1
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http special response: 301, "/?"
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http set discard body
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 uploadprogress error-tracker error: 301
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 uploadprogress error-tracker not tracking in this location
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 xslt filter header
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Date: Sat, 15 Dec 2018 14:19:27 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://beta.coralnotes.com/

2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 write new buf t:1 f:0 000000000120F4A0, pos 000000000120F4A0, size: 202 file: 0, size: 0
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:202
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http output filter "/?"
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http copy filter: "/?"
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 image filter
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 xslt filter body
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http postpone filter "/?" 000000000120F698
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 write old buf t:1 f:0 000000000120F4A0, pos 000000000120F4A0, size: 202 file: 0, size: 0
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 00000000008D74E0, size: 132 file: 0, size: 0
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 00000000008D7280, size: 53 file: 0, size: 0
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http write filter: l:1 f:0 s:387
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http write filter limit 0
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 writev: 387 of 387
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http write filter 0000000000000000
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http copy filter: 0 "/?"
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http finalize request: 0, "/?" a:1, c:1
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 set http keepalive handler
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http close request
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 http log handler
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 free: 00000000010314A0, unused: 8
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 free: 000000000120F070, unused: 2330
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 free: 0000000001212470
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 hc free: 0000000000000000
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 hc busy: 0000000000000000 0
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 tcp_nodelay
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 reusable connection: 1
2018/12/15 14:19:27 [debug] 20623#20623: *2 event timer add: 19: 65000:1544883632407

==> /var/log/nginx/access.log <==
141.101.104.185 - - [15/Dec/2018:14:19:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "curl/7.54.0"
```

Comment: *"...now I can't reach it..."* - you obviously can reach it since the HTTPS connection to this domain is successful which means that you get the correct certificate. Only, the server then issues a redirect then to some other domain. This redirect is not caused by the parts of the configuration you show. Which means it is caused either by parts of the configuration you don't show or by the application served by the webserver.

Comment: Disable CloudFlare while you work on this.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks for the tip, I'm enabling "development mode" while working on this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich right, I'll change the question. I'm moving some of the subdomains to a clean machine, I'll post complete configs if it's reproduced there.
One thing I can't understand is the first line of log, where the connection is on port 80 instead of 443...